# Is eating one whole olive considered as eating a kezayit?

Tags: blessing, food

Is eating one whole olive considered as a kezayit (for the purposes of a bracha acharona)? Or is the pit, which most people do not eat, not considered - making only the remainder of the olive (which of course is less than a kezayit) count towards the shiur?

Comment: I assume you aren't looking for answers that say modern olives are not the same size as olives were a few thousand years ago

Comment: ...who eats the pit?

Comment: Note that this might present other issues of eating an entire 'beriya', a complete object, which even if less than a kezayis, is discussed in the poskim as possibly needing a Bracha Achrona.

Comment: @Salmononius2 The Rema rules that without the pit it would not be considered a beriya.

Answer (score 14):

The Talmud explicitly addresses this.

[**Berachos 38b-39a**](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=1&daf=38b&format=pdf)

> אמר ליה רבי ירמיה לרבי זירא רבי יוחנן היכי מברך על זית מליח כיון
>   דשקילא לגרעיניה בצר בצר ליה שיעורא אמר ליה מי סברת כזית גדול בעינן
>   כזית בינוני בעינן (והא איכא) וההוא דאייתו לקמיה דרבי יוחנן זית גדול
>   הוה דאע"ג דשקלוה לגרעינותיה פש ליה שיעורא דתנן זית שאמרו לא קטן ולא
>   גדול אלא בינוני וזהו אגורי ואמר רבי אבהו לא אגורי שמו אלא אברוטי שמו
>   ואמרי לה סמרוסי שמו ולמה נקרא שמו אגורי ששמנו אגור בתוכו
>
> R. Jeremiah asked R. Zera: How could R. Johanan make a blessing over a
>   salted olive? Since the stone had been removed, it was less than the
>   minimum size! — He replied: Do you think the size we require is that
>   of a large olive? We require only that of a medium sized olive, and
>   that was there, for the one they set before R. Johanan was a large
>   one, so that even when its stone had been removed it was still of the
>   requisite size. For so we have learnt: The ‘olive’ spoken of means
>   neither a small nor a large one, but a medium one. This is the kind
>   which is called aguri. R. Abbahu, however, said: Its name is not aguri
>   but abruti, or, according to others, samrusi. And why is it called
>   aguri? Because its oil is collected [agur] within it. ([Soncino
>   translation](https://halakhah.com/pdf/zeraim/Berachoth.pdf))

In other words the size of a kezayis is the size of a medium olive including the pit. Therefore, eating a medium olive without the pit would not be considered eating a kezayis, but eating a large olive without the pit would be considered eating a kezayis.

Answer (score 2):

No.

If we understand a *[kezayit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kezayit)* to be the volume of an olive (rather than a complex measure per R' Chaim Naeh *et al.*), then a single olive is not a kezayit, as the pit is considered within this volume.

In this case, a kezayit would be about one and one half olives, excluding their pits.

As always, [CYLOR](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9146/why-is-it-necessary-to-ask-a-rabbi)